# Как сделать, чтобы текст с кнопки в Tkinter (Python) отправлялся в консоль

Tags: python, tkinter, button

Есть код. Но не могу сделать так, чтобы текст с кнопки отсылался в консоль. Тоесть: нажал кнопку, текст с кнопки отобразился в консоли.

```py
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import *
    from PIL import ImageTk, Image
    
    #Панель управления
    def show_image(path):
        root = tk.Tk()
        img = Image.open(path)
        width = 500
        ratio = (width / float(img.size[0]))
        height = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(ratio)))
        imag = img.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imag)
        panel = tk.Label(root, image=image)
        panel.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="no")
    
        tk.Button(root, text='Запуск', command=root.quit).place(x=250, y=250)
    
        root.mainloop()
    
    show_image('C:/Users/111/Рабочий стол/Новая папка/Новая папка (3)/хлам/БОЛЬШАЯ ФЕРМА.jpg')
```

Answer (score 1):

Всё разобрался. Нужно было просто добавить класс `

> def root_quit():

`Вот код исправленный:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def root_quit():
    print("Some text")
#Панель управления
def show_image(path):
    root = tk.Tk()
    img = Image.open(path)
    width = 500
    ratio = (width / float(img.size[0]))
    height = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(ratio)))
    imag = img.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imag)
    panel = tk.Label(root, image=image)
    panel.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="no")

    tk.Button(root, text='Запуск', command=root_quit).place(x=250, y=250)

    root.mainloop()

show_image('C:/Users/111/Рабочий стол/Новая папка/Новая папка (3)/хлам/БОЛЬШАЯ ФЕРМА.jpg')
```